# Future earth, dystopian fantasy novel. Late 20th century scifi/fantasy

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I listened to the audio-recorded reading of the first chapter or so of a book (probably illegally uploaded) on YouTube in 2016.

This book seemed old; I'd date this work back to anywhere between 1960 through to early 1980.

The setting was a postnuclear Holocaust Earth where tribes, kingdoms and warlords clashed.  There was magic or the belief in magic as it was remembered when a necromancer had threatened the balance of power in a time shortly before our story.  There were also monsters, likely the result of genetic misshaping, that stalked the land.  One such monster actually was the subject of the first scene. I'll describe it as it encounters the character.

The first and only character I met in this chapter (or prologue) was an older man, considered a knight/hero of times past but perhaps on the decline; he had proven himself in battle and defended the common folk from danger in tempestuous times.  He was a leader or at least a great warrior.

In the first scene the hero was traveling and happened upon a bog.  In this bog he reflected on the danger of such places, noting mentally that a particular type of swamp creature roamed such environs; though nearly extinct following the defeat of the aforementioned necromancer, there still lingered reports of fighters going missing in the wilds these beasts were said to roam.  One that was intelligent, cruel, had a taste for men and horses and maybe enjoyed torture. (I remember it being called a gibbeth/gibbon/G-something) This thing was definitely a product of radiation and nature and perhaps dark magic because it bore a resemblance to humanity in its face, its intellect and its tactical awareness (preferring ambush tactics).

Well, it so happens that our main character witnesses a herd of horses fleeing away from this swampy area.  The fear in their eyes indicates that in fact one of these monsters was accosting them.  Horses were highly revered in this setting, so the hero investigates.  He finds the monster responsible in pursuit of the prey not long after, and though these predators were more than a match for several men, the hero engages. The hero outwits the creature by pretending to be injured by one of its attacks and baits it into a decapitating counterstrike. It dies headless with the relishing smile still on its face at the prospect of dragging our hero off.

Comment: I'm sure it's not correct for your question, but for some reason aspects of this remind me of the Shanarra books by Terry Brooks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [Michael Moorcock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Moorcock)'s 1967 novel [*The Jewel In the Skull*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jewel_in_the_Skull), which is the first of his *Dorian Hawkmoon* series *[History of the Runestaff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_the_Runestaff)*. The character Dorian Hawkmoon is one of Moorcock's [Eternal Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Champion) incarnations. The four book *History of the Runestaff* series was collected into a single omnibus edition in 1979.

At the start of the book, which takes place in a quasi-feudal future post-apocalyptic setting, Count Brass is touring a boggy part of his territory (called the "Kamarg", which occupies part of present day France), when, after horses including his own mount are spooked, he is attacked by a ferocious 8-foot high mutant creature which slithered on its belly (a "baragoon, the 'marsh gibberer'") with a hankering for the taste of human flesh ("delighting in eating a man's limbs before his eyes"). He outwits the creature by speaking to it boldly and falsely offering it mercy, and then dispatches it much as you describe: "…the baragoon's head flopped half off its shoulders, blood pumped again, and the body fell." The baragoons were created by a sorcerer who used to control the land, by distorting and mutating human men.

Below is a tiny selection of some of the many book covers of the standalone novel:

[image: Book cover for The Jewel in the Skull]
[image: Book cover for The Jewel in the Skull]
[image: Book cover for The Jewel in the Skull]

An audio-reading of the whole book by William P. Fletcher was available (access date 1-2-2022) on YouTube, but has since been take down at the request of Moorcock.

Comment: I don't remember any post-nuclear, apocalyptic stuff in this story. Just plain old swords and sorcery, albeit with a Moorcockian multiverse touch.

Comment: @Spencer Yeah…. I think you are correct about that, and that was a detail I mistakenly added. Editing now.

Comment: In present-day France, by the way, the Camargue is the delta of the Rhône.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds vaguely like Hiero's Journey (Sterling Lanier, 1973), summarized in [this post on Tor.com](https://www.tor.com/2020/08/13/a-post-apocalyptic-quest-through-the-wilderness-hieros-journey-by-sterling-e-lanier/):
"The novel opens with Per Hiero Desteen, Secondary Priest-Exorcist, Primary Rover and Senior Killman of the Church Universal, traveling through a swamp with his Bull Morse, Klootz (a morse being a moose bred to be ridden like a horse). Hiero has telepathic powers, which include telepathy and weak powers of precognition. He has a telepathic rapport with Klootz, who has a sardonic and delightfully non-anthropomorphic personality."

So we've got a post-holocaust knight traveling through a swamp -- though the monster in this encounter is a giant snapping turtle. If this is the story you're looking for, perhaps that incident is later in the book. He also later comes across a mutant bear named Gorm, though it becomes an ally. The major opposition are the Unclean, an order that controls mutant animals.